# Loads of wierd undefined references compiling boost program with mudflap

Tags: c++, boost, compilation

I'm writing a program in C++ on Linux using the Boost library. I have a wild memory read that's causing a problem so I'd like to compile using the mudflap library. However, at the link stage I get hundreds of undefined references: things such as

```
mpl_::int_<3>::value
__gnu_cxx::__numeric_traits_floating<long double>::__max_exponent10
vtable for boost::gregorian::bad_weekday
typeinfo for boost::detail::sp_counted_impl_p<boost::detail::future_object<void> >
```

What am I missing?

The version of boost is 1.49 and of gcc is 4.7.0 (CVS 20120505).

Comment: and show command line for your compile and link

Comment: It is difficult to answer such a question without seeing any of your code.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it's not anything specific to this program because it compiles and (mainly) works fine without the mudflap option. However, I'll leave this question for a while and see if I can demonstrate this with a small program. The source code in question is several hundred K in size.

Answer (score 0):

In case your C++ file reduces to some definitions after the preprocessor run, it might help to add some public variable. At least it helped for me.

Comment: The question is: Does it help? Well, it's a hack, but better having a hack than nothing. In case you have a solution, you could add your anwer.